# SSIS to extract different data tables from one csv file

Tags: csv, ssis, extract

I have problem understanding how could I extract data from this file:

```
0|V1102299|USA05639|A&P POLYCHEM|20110214|49896.0000 |0.0000 
1|V1102299|00001|USA05639|A&P POLYCHEM|20110222|DOA100||Di Octyl Adipate      210KG/DR|16800.000 |KG|2970.0000 
2|V1102299|00001|00|20130617|5000010209||16800.000 ||49896.0000 
4|USA05639|A&P POLYCHEM|FRB1|Freight (Value)|4100.000000000 |USD
4|USA05639|A&P POLYCHEM|ZL02|Fuel (value)|0.000000000 |USD
4|USA05639|A&P POLYCHEM|ZL01|Temp Control (value)|0.000000000 |USD
4|USA05639|A&P POLYCHEM|ZOB1|Customs (Value)|0.000000000 |USD
4|USA05639|A&P POLYCHEM|ZL03|Haz. Mat. (value)|0.000000000 |USD
```

where first column indicates row type:

- `0` is root element **(required)**
- `1` is child **(optional, multiple)**
- `2` is child **(optional, multiple)**
- `3` is child **(optional, multiple)**
- `4` is child **(optional, multiple)**

And extract to multiple tables with corresponding line columns and keep relationship between lines.
Each row has it's own set of column count and column names, types.

**Note:** I have no control what so ever regarding how I receive this csv file. I personally know this is terrible practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how we cope with such problems: in general, you'll have to divide the process into parts:

1. Splitting csv file.
2. Reading different file types.

Ad 1. Put a `Data Flow` to Read the input csv file.

- Start with `Flat File Source` as only one column (`Column1`), of string type. We do it only to get the row type you mentioned.
- Use `Transformation Component` to split this line into pieces. Get the first value (your type identifier) and set it as OutputBuffer (`ResultBuffer`) column named `TypeID`:

.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
   var arr = Row.Column1.Split('|'); // Splitting the rows of Names column
   ResultBuffer.AddRow();
   ResultBuffer.TypeID = arr[0];
}
```

- With a `Conditional Split` check the type:
  `TypeID == 0` (similar for the others). After this, just a normal `Flat File Destination`, to save to a filename `TypeID_file.txt` the one column you've read.

Ad 2.
Create a `Data Flow` with 5 separate containers to read from each created file separately, with properly set column names and types.